# ASP .NET Core: Editable Grid: Insert dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-core

**Objetive:** I'm trying to construct a view where the records from a table (machines) can be updated in a grid, and that each atribute of each record has the option to be chosen from a dropdownlist.

This is my Get method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            return View(await _context.Machines.Include(t => t.MachineTypes).Include(p => p.Suppliers).Include(s=>s.Stores).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
        }
```

And this is the definition for the dropdown list:

```
private void PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListStore(object selectedStore = null)
        {
            var typequery = from k in _context.Stores
                            orderby k.StoreName
                            select k;
            ViewBag.StoreID = new SelectList(typequery.AsNoTracking(), "StoreID", "StoreName", selectedStore);
        }
```

Now, to the View:

Model:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>
```

Since I need all the registers. Then the table.

Header:

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MchName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StoreID)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Body:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MchName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="StoreID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <select asp-for="StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Tienda --
 </option>
                                </select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
} 
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**Question:** I've read that is not best to use a *div* inside a *td* but it may work, altough there may be better options. Which would be the best practice?

**Question:** Well, this is a Test but I'm getting this error:
"'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'StoreID' and no extension method 'StoreID' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I can't track the error. For me it looks fine and I don't know why it can't read the StoreID. I wonder if it's for the "asp-for" inside the div. I don't know.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks